# Erro de sintaxe da Media Query ao compactar o código

Tags: css, media-queries, syntax-error

Estou tentando compactar ao máximo o site de onde trabalho e para isso estou minificando ao máximo os javascripts e css, porém esta dando erro ao minificar o css bem nos códigos parecidos com o que colocarei aqui em baixo. Ele faz a validação da sintaxe e ele considera essa declaração de Media Query dentro da classe principal como um erro de sintaxe, ele até funciona e deixa passar, porém ao compactar e jogar no servidor ele dá problema. Alguém sabe por que acontece isso e como resolver?

Segue um exemplo:

.img-header-home-01 {

```
background-image: url("../imagens/home/slider-01.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center center;

@media (max-width: @iphone-screen) {
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

}

Comment: Já tentou usar o valor do `iphone-screen` direto em px ou rem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudei um pouco sua sintaxe e funcionou! Segue o exemplo:

```
.img-header-home-01 {

background-image: url("../imagens/home/slider-01.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center center;

}

@media (max-width: @iphone-screen) {
    .img-header-home-01 {
         background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

E mificado ficaria assim:

```
.img-header-home-01{background-image:url(../imagens/home/slider-01.jpg);background-size:cover;background-attachment:scroll;background-position:center center}@media (max-width:@iphone-screen){.img-header-home-01{background-attachment:scroll}}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito Obrigado!